F10 not working while using Key Enum Visual studio
I am making a keyboard testing program for my school project. Everything is working great except the F10 key. Every time I press it, it gives me the error noise, and I have to click my window again to continue. If pressed, it should make a green rectangle. Hopefully, someone can help.
Thanks.
case Key.F10:
    F10.Fill = Brushes.Green;
    break;

<!--F10-->
<Rectangle x:Name="F10" Fill="LightGray" Margin="416,25,359,384" Width="25" Height="25">
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="KeyDown"></EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
<TextBlock Text="F10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="419,29,0,0"/>

I've tried using the settings to stop F10 from being a function key. It is used for StepOVer while debugging. I've installed Visual Studio Commander to try and get rid of it. All with no result.

Instead of using EventTriggers, you couldhandle the KeyDown event in your code-behind. The SystemKey property will tell you which System key was pressed.
<Window x:Class="KeyEnumn.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KeyEnumn"  
        mc:Ignorable="d" PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="39" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="rF10" Fill="LightGray" Margin="416,25,359,384" Width="25" Height="25">
           
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="F10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="419,29,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

   private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       switch (e.Key)
       {
           case Key.System:
               if (e.SystemKey == Key.F10)
               {
                   rF10.Fill = Brushes.Green;
                   break;
                   e.Handled = true;
               }
               break;
       }
   }


This works, thank you so much. It still pulls me out of my window but its allright. Thanks again!
